# How do I pad a printf to take account of negative signs and variable length numbers?

Tags: c, formatting, floating-point, printf

I'm trying to output some numbers in a log file and I want to pad a load of floats via the `printf` function to produce:

```
 058.0
 020.0
 038.0
-050.0
 800.0
 150.0
 100.0
```

Currently I'm doing this:

```
printf("% 03.1f\n", myVar);
```

...where myVar is a float. The output from that statement looks like this:

```
58.0
20.0
38.0
-50.0
800.0
150.0
100.0
```

From [what I've read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) I would expect my code to produce the output I mentioned at the top of this post, but clearly something is wrong. Can you only use one flag at a time? ..or is there something else going on here?

Comment: You probably should be using proper C++ streams for I/O if this is _really_ a C++ question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The width specifier is the complete width:

```
printf("%05.1f\n", myVar);  // Total width 5, pad with 0, one digit after .
```

To get your expected format:

```
printf("% 06.1f\n", myVar);
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. I hadn't realised the padding included the decimal point etc. ...although it needs to be 06 to include the space or sign value.

Answer (score 1):

follows Erik,
but I find

```
printf("% 6.1f\n", myVar);
```

also works.