# Java Format negative Integer

Tags: java, format, int

I try to format integers so they always have four proper digits, that is, I want 0s for padding.

I have tried `"%04d"` which works nicely for positive number. For negatives it gives things like `-[854]` where I need `-[0854]`.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post code you tried?

Comment: (you may be confused with the above comment. You can try explaining more, that is, `int i=1;System.out.printf("%04d",i);` instead of just `"%04d"`)

Comment: Also, [instead of "thank you" you can just upvote/accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pad a printf to take account of negative signs and variable length numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325169/how-do-i-pad-a-printf-to-take-account-of-negative-signs-and-variable-length-numb)

Comment: (wait, that's C, but it also works here, use `"% 05d"`, see the 4th flag [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax))

Answer (score 1):

```
if(number>=0){ 
    String.format("%04d",number); 
}else{
     String.format("%05d",number); 
    }
```