# Display C Matrix with negative and positive numbers

Tags: c, matrix, printf

I was given a problem that needs to transform a matrix using a specific rule and then print it.

I have a 10x20 double matrix that I need to display in the command prompt using C. However, when it has negative numbers it becomes unorganized. My printing function is this:

```
int print(const double f[N][M])
{
    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<M; j++)
        {
            printf ("%.2f ", f[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
```

Thanks in advance for your help![image]

Comment: This looks completely fine to me. What do you mean by "it becomes unorganized"?

Comment: You need to specify the max width a float value can take(include `.` & decimals) in `printf ("%6.2f "`. Look for width [printf()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: @SparKot That would be *minimum* field width.

Comment: I assume `N` and `M` are previous `#define`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "disorganized" you mean that your columns aren't properly aligned. (I can't see anything else wrong with it.) Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325169/how-do-i-pad-a-printf-to-take-account-of-negative-signs-and-variable-length-numb):

TL;DR:

```
printf("% 6.1f\n", f[i][j]);
```

Substitute your desired value for the "6" in that statement.